# Tarski's semantic conception of truth and logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Tarski's semantic conception of truth states: $X$ is true iff p (where $p$ is a sentence, and $X$ is the name of the sentence $p$ to which the truth predicate applies).

However, in logic, to express the idea that a sentence $p$ is true, we just say $v(p)=1$.

Does Tarski's semantic conception of truth have any use in formal logic? Put differently, do logicians always implicitly mean $v(p)=1$ iff $p$ when they speak about the truth of $p$?

Comment: Well... there's the completeness theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is not exactly what I asked. What I want to know is whether or not logicians mean $v(p)=1$ iff $p$ when they speak about the truth of $p$?

Comment: Please provide some context or references. Your question is unanswerable as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

In *propositional logic* the "semantic values" available for (classical) propositional letters : $p,q,\ldots$ are just two: **TRUE** and **FALSE**.

Thus, nothing changes if instead of *true* and *false* we use $1$ and $0$.

Things are different with more complex languages, like *first order logic*.

In this case, to say that a f-o arithmetical sentence like:

> $\exists x \ (x < 0)$

is *true* in the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers amounts to, according to Tarski's definition, to assert that there is a *number* $n$ (i.e. an element of $\mathbb N$) such that $n$ is less than the number *zero*, and this is a legitimate (i.e. meaningful) assertion, and it is *false*.

See [First-order languages and structures](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modeltheory-fo/#Lang).